# Range.InsertXML throws when inserting Open XML

Tags: .net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, openxml-sdk

I'm writing a VSTO add-in for Word. I'm manipulating some content controls and have their `Range` objects.

I'm trying to use the Open XML SDK to create XML element objects (`OpenXmlElement`) such as a Run (`Run`/`w:r`) and properties for it. Here's the XML:

```
<w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:rPr>
    <w:b />
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>Hello world this should be bold</w:t>
</w:r>
```

When I pass this to `Range.InsertXML`, I get

> XML markup cannot be inserted in the specified location.

From what I've seen is that perhaps my XML isn't formatted properly. I've also included a XML declaration with no success.

What format should I use to pass Open XML strings into `InsertXml`?

**Edit**
I'm creating a document this way to use the flat XML model discussed below:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using (Wordprocessing document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart part = document.AddMainDocumentPart();
    Body body = new Body(new Paragraph(new Run(new RunProperties(new Bold()),
        new Text("Hello world this should be bold"))));
    mainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(body);
    document.Save();

    string xml = document.ToFlatOpcString();
    range.InsertXml(xml);
}
```

Now I get an exception with the OpenXML SDK.

> Root element is missing.

```
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.GetContentsAsXml(PackagePart part)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.<>c.<ToFlatOpcDocument>b__109_0(PackagePart part)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddContentSkipNotify(Object content)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.ToFlatOpcDocument(XProcessingInstruction instruction)
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument.ToFlatOpcDocument()
at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.ToFlatOpcString()
... my stack
```

Comment: For me your code works, the text gets inserted (after fixing spelling `Wordprocessing`, `mainDocumentPart` and `InsertXml`).

Answer (score 0):

The essential part is that you need valid WordOpenXML OPC flat-file format (lots of techy ECMA info if you google that, and also read info written by Eric White) for formatted Word content. You can see what that involves by getting the WordOpenXML from a Range, then writing that out. For example what the variable `x` contains in this VBA code:

```
Sub WriteWordOpenXML()
    Dim docSource As word.Document
    Dim docTarget As word.Document
    Dim x As String

    Set docSource = ActiveDocument
    x = docSource.content.Text
    Set docTarget = Documents.Add
    docTarget.content.InsertXML x
End Sub
```

The result is extremely verbose and you wouldn't need all of it. The tricky part is knowing exactly how much you need. And how much you need depends on exactly what you want to insert. As a rule of thumb, you don't need the parts or namespaces that aren't involved in what's being inserted. If there's no graphic involved, everything to do with graphics can safely be left out, for example.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml#main) explains in simple terms what the minimum Word Open XML is for some kinds of content and how to use the OPC flat-file format. The content is too long to include in a Stack Overflow post.

Comment: i dont have another `word.Document`, i'm going to have a bunch of xml strings.

Comment: You don't have to have one for your final solution. But you need one in order to *develop* your solution - to get that "wrapping" WordOpenXML. It can be quite a steep learning curve. If it's too much effort, perhaps better stick to Word's object model...

Comment: i've updated my question with what i assume is the correct format but the sdk is now failing.